# virtual box sees usb but failed to attach usb device on virtual machine?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kali-linux, usb

I have same issue on kali and mint.

I installed extention box and virtualbox guest additions.

Install vboxusers:   `sudo groupadd vboxusers`

Add my username on it :`sudo usermod -aG vboxusers myUserName`

ejected usb device from the host os.

enabled  usb controller. tried all of 3.

However i still cannot use usb device on my linux machine. it sees all the connected usb devices but fails to attach it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the USB device is not used by the host machine. Restart VB machine being sure the USB is not in host.
Sorry if you already try that  !

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows as Host?

This issue drove me nuts for months.  Until I came across these threads:
https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/230064-usb-problem-driving-me-nuts-3.html
https://mooremn.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/vmware-player-error-host-usb-device-connections-disabled/

Apparently, windows has a flag where it will convert usb device names to upper or lower names for filters.  So the Host can still see the device, but the Guest cannot attach due to the different case.  Deleting the registry entry preserves the name case.